# esp8266 How can I update data on all connected clients (Slider and Selectbox)?

Tags: javascript, html, arduino, esp8266

I have written a program with the Arduino IDE for an esp-12. With this program I can select the speed, brightness, and effect for a WS2812 LED strip over Wi-Fi. I can connect with any smartphone to the access point (ESP-12), then an HTML site is displayed with the sliders and a selectbox. It works fine.

My goal:
When a connected user makes changes on the ESP website then the website (sliders and selectbox) of all other connected users should be updated immediately. The maximum of possible connected users is 3.

If a user drags the slider then the ESP-12 hangs a lot.

Here is my Arduino code:

```c++
#define WEBSOCKETS_NETWORK_TYPE NETWORK_ESP8266_ASYNC

void webSocketEvent(uint8_t num, WStype_t type, uint8_t * payload, size_t lenght) { // When a WebSocket message is received
  switch (type) {
    case WStype_DISCONNECTED:             // if the websocket is disconnected
      Serial.printf("[%u] Disconnected!\n", num);
      break;
    case WStype_ERROR: {                 // websocket connection error
        String payloadString=(const char *)payload;
        Serial.println("error: "+payloadString);
    }
    break;
    // new client connected 
    case WStype_CONNECTED: {              
        IPAddress ip = webSocket.remoteIP(num);
        Serial.printf("[%u] Connected from %d.%d.%d.%d url: %s\n", num, ip[0], ip[1], ip[2], ip[3], payload);
        // update website of new connected client with current data
         webSocket.broadcastTXT('*'+String(effekt_name));
         webSocket.broadcastTXT('-'+String(animation_speed));
         webSocket.broadcastTXT('+'+String(helligkeit));
      }
      break;
    case WStype_TEXT:                    
      // receive data 
      Serial.printf("[%u] get Text: %s\n", num, payload);
      /* Effekt */
     if (payload[0] == '*') {            // we get effekt back
         String payloadString=(const char *)payload;
         String text = String((char *) &payload[1]);
         effekt_name = text;
         Serial.println("effekt: "+effekt_name);         
      }
     /* Brightness */
     if (payload[0] == '+') {            // we get brightness back
         String payloadString=(const char *)payload;
         String text = String((char *) &payload[1]);
         helligkeit = text.toInt();
         FastLED.setBrightness(helligkeit);
         Serial.println("brightness: "+text);

      }
     /* Speed */
     if (payload[0] == '-') {            // we get speed back
         String payloadString=(const char *)payload;
         String text1 = String((char *) &payload[1]);
         animation_speed = atoi((const char*)&payload[1]);    
         Serial.println("payload "+payloadString);
         Serial.println(animation_speed, DEC);
      }
      break;
  }
}

void loop() {
  if (effekt_name == "Confetti") {
    if (last_effekt != "Confetti") {
      last_effekt = "Confetti";
      all_off();
    }
    confetti1a();
  } 
  if (effekt_name == "Flashes") {
    if (last_effekt != "Flashes") {
      last_effekt = "Flashes";
      all_off();
    }
    flashes1a();
  } 
  if (effekt_name == "Juggle") {
    if (last_effekt != "Juggle") {
      last_effekt = "Juggle";
      all_off();
    }
    juggle1a();
  }

  // send data (slider and selectbox) to all clients 
  if (millis()>wait001){
    webSocket.broadcastTXT('*'+String(effekt_name));
    webSocket.broadcastTXT('-'+String(animation_speed));
    webSocket.broadcastTXT('+'+String(helligkeit));
    wait001=millis()+websockMillis;  
  }  
}
```

Here is my JavaScript code:

```js
var websock;
function start() {
  websock = new WebSocket('ws://' + window.location.hostname + ':81/');
  websock.onopen = function(evt) { console.log('websock open'); };
  websock.onclose = function(evt) { console.log('websock close'); };
  websock.onerror = function(evt) { console.log(evt); };

  websock.onmessage = function(evt) {
    console.log(evt);
    if (evt.data.substring(0,1)=="*") {
    document.getElementById("idOfSelectInput").value = (evt.data.substring(1,evt.data.length));
    }
    if (evt.data.substring(0,1)=="-") {
    document.getElementById('speed').value = (evt.data.substring(1,evt.data.length));
    }
    if (evt.data.substring(0,1)=="+") {
    document.getElementById('brightness').value = (evt.data.substring(1,evt.data.length));
    }

    function effekt() {
        var x = document.getElementById("idOfSelectInput").value;   
        websock.send('*'+x);    
        console.log('effekt: ' + value); 
    }
    function brightness() {
        var b = document.getElementById('brightness').value; 
        websock.send('+'+b);    
        console.log('brightness: ' + b); 
    }
    function speed() {
        var s = document.getElementById('speed').value; 
        websock.send('-' + s);  
        console.log('brightness: ' + s); 
    }

  } 
}
```

Here is my HTML code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
  <title>LED Control</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8"> 
  <link href='main.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="/apple-touch-icon-180x180.png">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="144x144"  href="/favicon-144x144.png">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="48x48" href="/favicon.ico">
  <link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json">
  <meta name="theme-color" content="#00878f">
  <meta content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0' name='viewport'>
  <script src="WebSocket.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="jscolor.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body onload="javascript:start();">
  <center>
    <header>
      <h1>LED Control</h1>
    </header>
    <div>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td style="width:14.4px; text-align: right">Helligkeit: </td>
          <td><input class="enabled" id="brightness" type="range" min="5" max="255" step="5" oninput  ="brightness();" value="50"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td style="width:1.4px; text-align: right"><br></td>
          <td><br></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td style="width:14.4px; text-align: right">Geschwindigkeit: </td>
          <td><input class="enabled" id="speed" type="range" min="1" max="50" step="1" oninput  ="speed();" value="5"></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>

    <div>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td style="width:14.4px; text-align: right">Effekt: </td>
          <td style="width:auto;">
            <select onchange="effekt1()" name="select" style="width: 200px" id="idOfSelectInput"> 
              <option value='1'>Rainbow</option> 
              <option>Confetti</option> 
              <option>Flashes</option> 
            </select>
          </td>
          <td style="width: 100%; text-align: right"> 
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>    
  </center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: please can someone help?

Comment: look into debouncing the "slider", which can fire dozens even hundreds of times a second, overloading the ESP. You should also move the code in `WStype_CONNECTED` to a function, and call then when a new value comes in to push out that value to the connected clients.

Comment: thank you for your answer.
This was my debouncing:    if (millis()>wait001){

Are there other ways to debounce the slider?

In WStype_CONNECTED are only events if a client does connect the first time. here do i send the actual settings to this client.